# Conditionally include GLES2 where needed

Tags: opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to use functions such as `glCreateShader`, `glGetShaderiv`, `glDeleteProgram` but they don't exist when I import `GL/gl.h` or `GL/glext.h` on a Linux system.

This is probably because its a laptop from 2008 with the integrated graphics reporting:

> 2.1 Mesa 20.1.10

and the discrete card:

> 3.0 Mesa 20.1.10

When I import `GLES2/gl2.h` then everything works fine and the includes are resolved.

Now I don't currently have access to a desktop computer or one with sufficiently higher graphics standard for at least a month - I'm *assuming* that these better systems have shader functionality included in the standard `GL/gl.h` file.

How can I write a conditional import to require GLES only where needed? I don't want to have to add a variable to the *Makefile*, I want to be able to automatically be able to detect a system where these symbols are only available as GLES components at compile time with `#ifdef` sequences.

Comment: You have to use an OpenGL loader like [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Will this work with SDL2?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Alright, I'll give glew a go and report back.

Comment: This has nothing to do with sdl. OpenGL (ES) is a specification. The loader gives you access to the API functions which are provided by the graphics driver.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Well that was... to put it simply, **easy**. Including `GL/glew.h` and removing all other includes has fixed it - thank you very much. If you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: As for SDL, I think I'm just getting mixed up with GL, glu, GLUT, GLFW, glew, etc. nevermind me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an OpenGL loader like [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/). OpenGL (ES) is a specification. The loader gives you access to the API functions which are provided by the graphics driver.

See [OpenGL Loading Library - glad](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#glad_.28Multi-Language_GL.2FGLES.2FEGL.2FGLX.2FWGL_Loader-Generator.29):

```cpp
const SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
if (context == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "SDL could not create context";
    return 1;
}

if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize OpenGL context" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

See [Initialize GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/):

```cpp
const SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
if (context == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "SDL could not create context";
    return 1;
}

if {glewInit() != GLEW_OK}
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```